# How to index a multilanguage entity in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-12, collate, partial-index

Here I am creating table `product_feature_text`, having a 1:N relation with table `product`. As the application must support several user languages, a `lang_code` column is added to segment english texts from other language texts.

As I want to present the product features alphabetically ordered in every language, I have created four partial indexes with their specific `collate`. It is expected that all products features have `title` in all of the four languages, i.e., there will be 25% of rows with `lang_code = 'ES'`, for example.

This is an oversimplification of the real case but enough to depict the situation.

```sql
create table product_feature_text (
  id          bigint generated by default as identity primary key,

  -- reference to the parent product
  product_id  bigint not null,

  -- language dependent columns
  lang_code   char(2),
  title       varchar,

  foreign key (product_id) references product (id)
);

create index on product_feature_text (title collate "en-US") where lang_code = 'EN';
create index on product_feature_text (title collate "es-ES") where lang_code = 'ES';
create index on product_feature_text (title collate "fr_FR") where lang_code = 'FR';
create index on product_feature_text (title collate "de_DE") where lang_code = 'DE';
```

Is this the best index approach for the case?

Addendum from a comment: a typical query would be

```
select text
from product_feature
where product_id = 1024
   and lang_code = 'FR'
order by title collate "fr_FR"
```

where `product_id` could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the intended use of the indexes.

If you want to use them for

```
SELECT ... FROM product_feature_text
WHERE lang_code = 'EN' AND ...
ORDER BY title COLLATE "en-US";
```

your indexes might be useful.

Also, if your query looks like

```
WHERE product_feature_text > 'bhd'  COLLATE ...
```

it might help.

However, for most cases that I can envision, a single index whose collation doesn't matter would be better.

For the query in the addendum, the perfect index would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON product_feature (product_id, title COLLATE "fr_FR")
   WHERE lang_code = FR';
```

Comment: Thanks again @Laurenz Albe. Yes, a typical query would be `select text from product_feature where product_id = 1024 and lang_code = 'FR' order by title collate "fr_FR"` being `1024` any other valid product_id

Comment: For those 4 languages, `collate` would not help too much. Maybe the ß in deustch and some ç in french

Comment: I have added an index suggestion to the answer. If `product_id` is very selective, I'd prefer a simple indexon just that column. Having many indexes is bad for planning time.

Comment: A typical product may have 5-30 features. This means a total of 20-120 rows in `product_feature`  for a single product in the four languages. I understand that you suggest that scanning those rows is worth the pain of having 4 partial indexes.

Comment: I will be testing this empirically. Thank you!